# nginx mirror with socket.io

Tags: nginx, socket.io, mirror

I configured a mirror with nginx, but after some time (about 2 minutes) all socket.io connections disconnect from the mirror. I tried to modify timeouts and etc. but nothing changed.

Here my configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    listen [::]:443 default_server ssl;

    server_name www.myserver.net;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/my/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/my/key.pem;

    proxy_connect_timeout 7d;
    proxy_send_timeout 7d;
    proxy_read_timeout 7d;

    client_max_body_size 50m;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7000;
        #proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host "$server_addr:$server_port";

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        client_max_body_size 50m;
        mirror /mirror;
    }

    location /mirror {
      internal;
      resolver 8.8.8.8;
      proxy_pass https://bugfix.myserver.net$request_uri;
      proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
      proxy_set_header Host bugfix.apio.cloud;

      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_http_version 1.1;

      proxy_connect_timeout 7d;
      proxy_send_timeout 7d;
      proxy_read_timeout 7d;
    }
}
```

What's wrong in it?